# Is a shared Google Photos album publicly searchable?

Tags: google-search, privacy, google-photos, sharing, album

I'd like to share a Google Photos album only with one person and allow them to view and edit the album, but I do NOT want the album or any photos to come up in search results. I saw that [the only way to share an album results in generating a publicly accessible link](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-share-Google-Photos-album-with-selected-people-only/answer/Jordan-Phillips). Does this action also result in the photos and/or the album being searchable by the public?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 15 times. While the link might be helpful, questions should be self-contained. On the other hand, the question is based on an unreliable source. It doesn't quote official documentation or include information about what supports their claim.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you share it. If you share it with one person (or more people) like this than not:

[image: 0]

---

If you will share it via links on the bottom then it's kind of public:

[image: 0]

Comment: Don’t think this answers the question. “It’s kind of public.” But is it searchable?

Comment: if you mean if it's searchable via googling it - it's not. but if you tweet it then that tweet could be searched.

Comment: @MikeEng, in the second case, anyone, including search engines, can follow the generated URL and see the album. The last time I checked though, Google deliberately refrains from indexing the photos.